# Usermanagement in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

HI,
I am developing a userManagement Application in asp.net. I want to make the User Access page to control the permissions to the various user groups by administrator.I am developing this application reffered by website administration tool .
How can i make a good usermanagement application and how can i control the users to access the pages that they have permission.I am using VisualStudio2010.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  What specifically are you trying to do? Have you tried certain things already that aren't working? "How can I make a good xxx application" is far too broad for a single SO question.  Try getting a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Forms Authentication with User Roles which is built in asp.net 2.0 is your friend. This site might help you
[click](http://www.xoc.net/works/tips/forms-authentication.asp)